# Como fazer o Extent Reports gerar um relatório HTML quando o teste dá erro fora da tag @Test?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, relatório, testes-automatizados

Criei um modelo de relatório para o meu projeto de testes que está até o momento atendendo minha demanda, porém, caso o teste falhe fora da tag '@Test' o relatório não é gerado (sendo algum erro de conexão, ou erro no driver, etc). Acredito que isso acontece porque o teste não passa pelas tags @AfterMethod e @AfterTest quando erros desse tipo acontecem, e, portanto, não consigo executar os comandos extent.flush() e extent.close() e o arquivo html não é criado. Alguma sugestão do que posso fazer?
Segue código em Java abaixo:

```
@BeforeTest
public void startTest() {

    className = this.getClass().getName();
    String dateName = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hhmmss").format(new Date());
    String userDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
    nomePasta = className.replace("MOBILEX_AUTOMACAO.TEST.", "") + " " + dateName;

    new File(userDir + "\\target\\reports\\" + nomePasta);

    extent = new ExtentReports(userDir + "\\target\\reports\\" + nomePasta + "\\"
            + className.replace("MOBILEX_AUTOMACAO.TEST.", "") + "REPORT.html", true);
    extent.addSystemInfo("Nome APP", "MobileX");

    extent.loadConfig(new File(userDir + "\\extent-config.xml"));

}

@AfterMethod
public void getResult(ITestResult result) throws Exception {

    if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.FAILURE) {
        String screenshotPath = getScreenhot(result.getName());
        logger.log(LogStatus.FAIL, "Test Case Failed is " + result.getThrowable());
        logger.log(LogStatus.FAIL, "Test Case Failed is " + result.getName());

        logger.log(LogStatus.FAIL, logger.addScreenCapture(screenshotPath));
    } else if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.SUCCESS) {
        logger.log(LogStatus.PASS, "Test Case passed is " + result.getName());
    }

    extent.endTest(logger);
    DriverFactory.killDriver();
}

@AfterTest
public void endReport() throws IOException {

    extent.flush();
    extent.close();

}
```

Meu projeto de testes é para Mobile, estou utilizando o TestNG, versão 6.10 para os meus testes em Java, com o Appium versão 7.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você mudar isso:

```
@AfterTest
public void endReport() throws IOException {
    extent.flush();
    extent.close();
}
```

Pra isso:

```
@AfterTest(alwaysRun = true)
public void endReport() throws IOException {
    extent.flush();
    extent.close();
}
```

Ele vai passsar no flush e close, inclusive você pode usar também no @AfterMethod.
Segue a documentação: [TestNG](https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html)